# Using cookie authentication with bitbucket and curl

Tags: perl, curl, cookies, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to login with curl to Bitbucket server and use the created cookie to make another request, but somehow it is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $user        = 'user';
my $password    = 'pass';
my $base_url    = 'https://bitbucket.company.com/bitbucket';
my $project     = 'PROJ';
my $repository  = 'REPO';

my $login = `curl -s -u $user:$password --cookie-jar \"cookie.txt\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" \"$base_url/rest/api/1.0/projects\"`;
print $login;

my $url = $base_url.'/projects/'.$project.'/repos/'.$repository.'/settings/pull-requests';
my $pr_page = `curl -s --cookie \"cookie.txt\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"X-Atlassian-Token: no-check\" \"$url\"";
print $pr_page;
```

The login succeeds and I do get a cookie, it states:

> Netscape HTTP Cookie File
>   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
>   This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
>
> HttpOnly_bitbucket.mycompany.com  FALSE   /bitbucket/ TRUE    0   JSESSIONID  8079B4AC59C823137D7A78E4414C7CB3

But the script does not return the second page. I think it has something to do with not having the remember-me-cookie, but I can't generate it.

Thanks,
Rudy

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to be using `curl` over `LWP`?

Comment: @Sobrique mainly unfamiliarity with LWP. So it is no problem to use LWP.

Comment: @Sobrique do you have an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

or you could skip the login part and just steal the session from your UI browser and save it to a cookies file and passed that one to the curl obj conf calls
you could easily "steal" your current ui session in Chrome [with cookies export chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg) 
For the php junkies out there - the syntax is almost the same ...

```
    #
    # performs post or get http request , returns
    # usage:
    # ( $ret , $response_code , $response_body , $response_content )
    #     = $objUrlRunner->doRunURL( 'GET' , $url , $headers );
    #
    sub doRunURL {

        my $self               = shift ;
        my $http_method_type   = shift ;
        my $url                = shift ;
        my $headers            = shift ;

        my $cookies_file       = $appConfig->{'COOKIES_FILE'} ;
        $objLogger->doLogInfoMsg ( "cookies_file: " . $cookies_file ) ;

        my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new();

        ## Set up the standard GET/POST request options
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies_file );  # set where the cookies are stored
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_HEADER(),1);
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS(),3);
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_URL(), "$url" );
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);                  # Disable verbosity
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);                   # Don't include header in body
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);               # Disable internal progress meter
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);           # Disable automatic location redirects
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);              # Setting this to true fails on HTTP error
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);           # Ignore bad SSL
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);           # Ignore bad SSL
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);               # To make thread safe, disable signals
        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');          # Allow gzip compressed pages

        if ( $headers ) {
            for my $key ( sort ( keys %$headers )) {
                my $header_name = $key ;
                my $header_val = $headers->{ "$key" } ;
                $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER() , [ $header_name . $header_val ]  );
            }
        }

        if ( $http_method_type eq 'POST' ) {
            $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_POST(), 1);
        }

        # A filehandle, reference to a scalar or reference to a typeglob can be used here.
        my $response_body       = q{} ;
        my $response_code       = q{} ;
        my $response_content    = q{} ;

        $curl->setopt(WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_WRITEDATA(),\$response_body);

        # Starts the actual request
        my $ret = $curl->perform;


        if ($ret == 0) {
            my $msg = "OK for the curl transfer for the url: $url " ;
            $objLogger->doLogInfoMsg ( $msg ) ;

            $response_code = $curl->getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            $response_content = HTTP::Response->parse( "$response_body" ) ;
            $response_content = $response_content->content;

        } else {
            my $msg = "An error happened: $ret ".$curl->strerror($ret)." ".$curl->errbuf."\n" ;
            $objLogger->doLogErrorMsg ( $msg ) ;
            #  Error code, type of error, error message
        }

        return ( $ret , $response_code , $response_body , $response_content ) ;
    }
```